# How to get the index of the input in a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, string-formatting

I am trying to force a certain format into a textbox with the keypress method

```
private void textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
    switch (((TextBox)sender).Name){
        case "txtTitle":
            //code
            break;
        case "txtDate":
            if(txtDate.Text.Count() > 9) e.Handled = true;
            else{
                switch (txtDate.Text.Count()){
                    case 0: //0,1,2,3 (day)
                        e.Handled = (e.KeyChar > 47 && e.KeyChar < 52)?false:true; 
                        break;
                    case 1: //if last was 0,1,2 accept 0-9 (day)
                        if (txtDate.Text.Last() > 47 && txtDate.Text.Last() < 51) e.Handled = (e.KeyChar > 47 && e.KeyChar < 58)?false:true;
                        //if last was 3 accept 0,1
                        else if (txtDate.Text.Last() == 51) e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == 48 || e.KeyChar == 49)?false:true;
                        break;
                    case 2: case 5: // '/'
                        if (e.KeyChar != 47) e.Handled = true;
                        break;
                    case 3: //0,1 (month)
                        e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == 48 || e.KeyChar == 49)?false:true;
                        break;
                    case 4: //if last was 0 accept 0-9 (month)
                        if(txtDate.Text.Last() == 48) e.Handled = (e.KeyChar > 47 && e.KeyChar < 58)?false:true;
                        //if last was 0 accept 0-9
                        else e.Handled = (e.KeyChar > 47 && e.KeyChar < 51)?false:true;
                        break;
                    case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9: //0-9 (year)
                        e.Handled = (e.KeyChar > 47 && e.KeyChar < 58)?false:true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;
        case "txtBegin": case "txtEnd":
            //code
            break;
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == 8) e.Handled = false; //backspace
}
```

but when I have a complete date and I want to change any numbers I can't inforce chars because I am using the text count so is there any way to use the textbox's cursor position instead of the text count

Comment: As your code allows invalid dates to be entered (eg 31/02/2020) & you are going to have to validate those later - have you considered using a MaskedTextBox which will do some of the checking for you. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.validatingtype?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TextBox.SelectionStart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart) will give you the location of the caret.

> If no text is selected in the control, this property indicates the insertion point, or caret, for new text

That said, you are aware that there is already a control for capturing dates from a user? It's called the [`DateTimePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker). It has a [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format) property that can be used to control how the date is displayed to the user.

If you're using WPF, a quick look at the properties on `TextBox` shows that it has a [`TextBox.CaretIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex) to get you the location of the caret.

And the control for capturing a date from the user is [`DatePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker).